# Grouping single column string data fields into multiple columns using SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a table with a single column named 
Col-X with row values

```
AB-CD-E,
B-CD-EF,
B-KK-EFG,
B-KK-GFH,
B-XX-XYZ,
B-XX-ZZZ,
B-ZZ-EFX,
```

I want to group the data fields into different multiple columns by using the unique values such as "-CD-", "-KK-"... I would like my new table to have multiple columns with data fields like:

```
Col1    
AB-CD-E,    
B-CD-EF,

Col2    
B-KK-EFG,   
B-KK-GFH,   

Col3    
B-XX-XYZ, 
B-XX-ZZZ,

Col4
B-ZZ-EFX
```

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  (2) This type of transformation is typically done on the application side.

Comment: do you want to generate a report with that columns? or do you mean the fields of a table?

Comment: what DB ? does your unique value holds the same position as it appears in sample data or it may differ ...

Comment: I am using SQL DB and yes the unique value holds the same position as it appears in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you can group the data on the second part in each string by using group expression below:

=split(Fields!ColX.Value,"-")(1)

However, in SSRS, no matter in table or matrix, these data is only group on row group level, it can never be pivot into multiple columns. In a table, it can't make "AB-CD-E", "B-KK-EFG", "B-XX-XYZ", "B-ZZ-EFX" into a detail row. In a matrix, it will only show the first value within each group instance.